# Convert datetime to string with month name and return date NOT string

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert date(frensh) like this : 25/02/2019 => 25 Fév 2019
I can do it with string value:

```
date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

but this return string and I need a date type because I will use it in my chart as value.

I tried this :

```
var formats = new[] { "dd MMM yyyy" }; 
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("25/02/2019", DateFormat,
                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                         System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

but I get error

> "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime?"

Comment: The `DateTime` object is the same in both cases - there is no "conversion" here. What you are looking at is the format string used to represent the object. If your chart requires a `DateTime` object, then there most likely is a way to specify the format string to use to represent it.

Comment: `DateTime` has no format.  If you have a `DateTime` already and that's what you need for your chart, why are you trying to convert to a `string` in the first place?  Just use the `DateTime` value.

Comment: @RufusL there isn't String type in Y value in the Range Bar Chart

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I'm using datetime value from the datagrid and I display it in the chart but I didn't like I'm making Gantt chart it's not easily to read date with that format

Comment: I don't know about that control, but often there is some property like `AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";`

Comment: Is it [this control](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/htmlchart/chart-types/range-bar-chart)? If so, the link says, *"The inner tags of the axis tag can control the major and minor grid lines in terms of color and size **and the labels can have a DataFormatString**, position and visibility set through each inner tag's properties."*, which might be of use.

Comment: If your question is about how use a specific control, you should mention that in your question and provide the control's namespace and a link to the control documentation if possible. You should also show the actual line of code that's giving you the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find the solution by the suggestion of @Rufus L, I kept the value as Datatime then changed the LabelStyle

`AxisY.LabelStyle.Format="{0:dd MMM yyyy}"`

and I got my Gantt chart, thank you very much

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic question which new developers didn't learn the difference between a `DateTime` and it's *textual* representation (a.k.a. `string`). Don't worry, we all had the same issue.

A [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) does not have *any* format. It just have date and time values. And it calculates as a `long` called [`Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.7.2).

On the other hand, what you want, which is `25 Fév 2019`, is a *textual* representation of it, which means it is a `string`. You can't have a "25 Fév 2019" as a `DateTime`, but you can have it as a `string`.

Let's say you have a `"25/02/2019"` as `string` and you want to parse it to `DateTime`. In such a case, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` like you did.

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("25/02/2019", "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now you have a `DateTime`, and you can get it's *textual* (a.k.a string) representation with [`.ToString()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) and French (`fr-FR`) culture.

```
string myString = myDateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

BTW, in `fr-FR` culture, abbreviated month name is `févr.`, not `Fév`. As far as I can see, none of `fr`, `fr-FR` or `fr-CA` does have that string. To get what you want, you have to remove last 2 character and make the first character upper case.

[image]

Comment: Struggling to decide if I should downvote or upvote. Downvote since you answered a question, which you said yourself has been answered alot and can be easily found by searching for the error. Upvote because you explained it nicely.

Comment: Well, that's weird.  I'm able to replicate your observations (that the "three-letter" abbreviation for février is "févr." in both fr-FR and fr-CA).  I'm not a native French speaker, but I lived in the Montreal area for the first 34 years of my life.  The general (French) rule is that an abbreviation that ends in the same letter as the word-end doesn't take a period at the end (examples "St" and "Ste" for "Saint" and "Sainte", "Mme" for Madame", etc.)

Comment: @Flydog57 Oh, that's really an interesting information, thanks for that honestly. Looks like .NET Team followed the rule for the French abbreviated names as "if it is not the same with the original name, put a dot (`.`) at the end". For example "mai", "juin" and "mars" don't have the dot at the end since they have maximum four letter and don't need to shorten.

Comment: Look for "French" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation (the first thing I found): _In French, the period only follows an abbreviation if the last letter in the abbreviation is not the last letter of its antecedent: "M." is the abbreviation for "monsieur" while "Mme" is that for "madame"._  My guess is that this is a bug, but, because of the parsability of DateTime strings, fixing it would be a breaking change.

Comment: @Flydog57 That's a weird rule IMO. If we only follow that rule, "Mn.", "Mns." or "Mnsiu." can be the abbreviation for "monsieur" for example. How to choose which one "should" be? On the other hand, I don't call this a "bug". For .NET Team, I'm quite sure they have to decide a "rule" for abbreviations for any non-stabil culture that have those names. With that rule, they can say "Hey, there is no perfect rule for abbreviation of month names in French, so, we applied "that" rule in .NET Framework". Globalization and internatlization is hard. I'm quite sure they choose the best option for them.

Comment: No, the rule isn't "Pick any possible abbreviation for monsieur, but make sure to put a dot at the end if it doesn't end in 'r'".  The rule is, "given a word/abbreviation pair, if the word and the abbreviation both end in the same letter, no dot is needed on the abbreviation, otherwise, the abbreviation needs the dot"

Comment: More (mostly off-topic) info.  According to the Yale Univ library, `févr.`, with the dot is the correct abbreviation (https://web.library.yale.edu/cataloging/months).  I'm guessing it's done for consistency (all the other abbreviated months get a dot, and I'm sure someone in France will point out that the abbreviation doesn't end with the terminating "r", but instead with the "r" immediately after the "v").  Go figure.

Comment: thank you for the explanation @SonerGönül I want an abbreviation for months, I see that the problem is in chart